# Howto mysql multiple outfiles into a single compressed zip

Tags: mysql, zip, into-outfile

1. I am running Xubuntu 16.04 and MariaDB with MySQL.
2. These 3 files (customers.csv, items.csv, invoices.csv) are created by
   MySQL `INTO OUTFILE` commands as seen below.
3. These 3 files needs to go into a single zip file (report.zip).
4. The 3 files (customers.csv, items.csv, invoices.csv) don't need to be saved permanently as they only serve as temp files so that they can be packed into the zip file.

My sample MySQL outfile commands:

`SELECT customer_id, firstname, surname FROM customers
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/customers.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';`

`SELECT item_id, itemname, item_plu FROM items
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/items.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';`

`SELECT invoice_id, invoice_total FROM invoices
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/invoices.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';`

### Question

Do you guys know a MySQL command in which the `INTO OUTFILE` files go directly into a zip file without being stored as 3 additional separate files onto the disk?

Comment: Such command does not exist, you will have to implement a small wrapper. It might even be possible to get around temporary separate files completely, for example php is able to create a ZIP archive from arbitrary data, so you could "pipe" the output right into the archive instead of a file. Never tried myself, but should be possible.

Comment: arkasha, thank you for your input! Could you provide me with a sample wrapper, so I have something to start on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just read your question and I found the answer in the same time while I was looking for the same feature. So I share what I found :
Unfortunately, it seems that MySQL doesnt support direct output compression, this feature is requested but not implemented yet :

[This is the link](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=2276)

The best way in my knowledge to do that would be to do it in two steps :

1. Output
2. Zip with command line

Joffrey

Comment: Hi Joffrey, thanks a lot for your help! It is really appreciated.